# Method `each` giving conflicting results

Tags: ruby

I am working through some of the [RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com) problems. The problem is to write a method that returns `true` if all elements in the array passed to the method are `Fixnum`. The solution I came up with is:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
  array.each.is_a? Fixnum
end
puts array_of_fixnums?(arr)
```

This returns `false`, and I don't understand why. I used this code, and it makes me more confused:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.each do |x|
  puts "#{x}, #{x.is_a? Fixnum}"
end
exit
```

This returns:

```
1, true
2, true
3, true
```

If anyone can explain what's up with this, I would appreciate the  clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`each` returns an `Enumerator` of the collection to iterate, so

```
Enumerator.is_a? Fixnum # => false
```

Try this:

```
def array_of_fixnums?(array)
  array.all? { |x| x.is_a? Fixnum }
end
```